# How can I check if a thread is NULL

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm running a simple operation with a few instances of a class and I want to run this operation in a separate thread for each class.
If that same instance of that class wants to run that operation again, it has to wait for the previous operation within that instance to finish. 
However, another instance of the class should be able to start it's operation while the first instance is performing the same operation.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
#include <thread>
class MyClass
{
    void Operation(){Sleep(10000);}
    void LaunchOperation()
    {
        if(opThread != NULL) //Pseudo Code line
            opThread.join();
        opThread = std::thread(&MyClass::Operation, this);
    }

    std::thread opThread;
}
```

But the `if(opThread != NULL)` line is obviously not correct.

Is there a correct substitution for this, or am I taking the wrong approach?

Thanks
-D

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Only *pointers* can be null, threads, apples and musicals cannot be null.

Comment: That's my point, how can I check if that thread is not running or hasn't been created yet? The `if(opThread != NULL)` is just pseudocode

Comment: I would probably just use `std::future` and `std::async`.

Comment: You are likely looking for `opThread.joinable()`

Comment: @KerrekSB Now you have forced me to write Tron: The musical.

Comment: No no no, wait. There's no such thing as a  "non-running thread". Either a thread exists and runs, or there is no thread. Don't confuse a "thread" with a "`std::thread`". The latter is a C++ library class that *may* represent a (necessarily running) thread, or it may not. (And you query which one it is with the `joinable` member function.)

Comment: @user4581301: I'd watch that, though I think you might struggle to find sufficiently skilled performers.

Comment: @KerrekSB, in Windows, at least, the thread will continue to exist after it has stopped running if anybody has a handle open to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) member function:

```
void f(std::thread & t)
{
    if (t.joinable())
    {
        t.join();
    }
    t = std::thread(&X::foo, &obj, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thnak you, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that `joinable()` doesn't tell you a thread is currently running, only that it has run in the past and not yet been joined. To check if a thread is *currently running* currently requires platform specific code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That's a *really* slippery point. The join *is* the synchronization point, and there simply *is* no notion of "before", "after", "already", "still" until you have a synchronization point. Really all you can say is that after the join returns the thread is no longer running.