# When should you use std::thread::joinable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

It is stated on the site cppreference with respect to [std::thread::joinable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) :

> Checks if the thread object identifies an active thread of execution.
>   Specifically, returns true if get_id() != std::thread::id(). So a
>   default constructed thread is not joinable. A thread that has finished
>   executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an
>   active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

What follows on the [std::thread::join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) documentation:

> **Error Conditions**
>
> resource_deadlock_would_occur if this->get_id() ==
>   std::this_thread::get_id() (deadlock detected)

Is the only purpose of this method to detect such a situation?  We currently and brazenly only call thread->join without a joinable wrapper, what is the danger of such an approach?

Comment: The `std::thread::join` documentation says that you can't `join` your own thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, common sense also says that.

Comment: What does "this method" refer to? `join` or `joinable`?

Comment: [Example use of `joinable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42916152).

Comment: @DanielSanchez https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `joinable` when you have a `std::thread` object which may already have been joined, or may not reference an actual **t**hread **o**f **e**xecution (TOE - i.e., OS thread), and you want to join it if not already joined.

e.g. if you were implementing the proposed `joinable_thread` class, then the destructor would say `if(thr.joinable()) thr.join();`, to cover the case that someone already called `join` explicitly.

Comment: did you mean `if(thr.joinable()) thr.join();` ?

Comment: I found this short lecture (by Scott Meyers) very useful (the last ~15 minutes discuses the "join" issues regarding `std::thread`): https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler

Comment: Question: How do you handle race conditions on the joinable() itself. What happens if joinable() returns true, then the thread is joined elsewhere in-between joinable() and the join(), and now we try to join() again?

Comment: The `std::thread` object itself is not thread-safe. You should only be accessing it from one thread at a time, using external synchronization such as `std::mutex` if necessary.

Answer (score 12):

From the information you quoted:

> So a default constructed thread is not joinable.

There's your answer. If you don't know whether your thread was default constructed or not, you do not know whether it was joinable.

So, near the end of your program/function/routine, when you want to join the thread (and you do need to do this, before the `std::thread` goes out of scope), you must do it *conditionally*. And this is how you do that.

```
#include <thread>

void bar(const unsigned int);

/**
 * This class may be default-constructed (in which case it does nothing),
 * or constructed with an `unsigned int` argument which shall be passed
 * to `bar()` in a worker thread.
 */
struct Foo
{
   Foo() {}

   Foo(const unsigned int x)
      : doThingsThread([&]() { bar(x); })
   {}

   ~Foo()
   {
      // The thread *MUST* be joined before destruction, if it
      // is joinable. Otherwise, it *CAN'T* be joined.
      if (doThingsThread.joinable())
         doThingsThread.join();
   }
private:
   std::thread doThingsThread;
};
```

Comment: +1 here for the extra info and example - exactly what I was looking for. Wandering if you can provide further clarification: From what I read (in other questions and from std::thread docs), if the thread is not joined when it is joinable then when the thread doThingsThread's destructor is called: `If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called. ` which means that your entire application will terminate because `std::terminate()` is called :o  ... this is what I understand anyway...

Comment: @code_fodder: No, because I did `doThingsThread.join()`, after which `joinable() == false` and therefore the thread's destructor is safe. Indeed, that's _why_ I do the `join`. You could think of `joinable()` as `needs_to_be_joined_please()`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking to clarify : ) "if the thread is `not` joined when it is joinable then...things go wrong". I was not saying you had not re-joined the thread, I was getting clarification on the "why" - i.e. if you don't then things can go wrong :o ... but anyway, it's clear now, thanks  : )