# Implementation of Microsoft's std::thread incompatible with specification?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio

Reference:

> checks if the std::thread object identifies an active thread of
> execution.

> Specifically, returns true if get_id() != std::thread::id()

In the end, all the function does is compare the thread's identifier against 0.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

Actual code (thread):

```
_NODISCARD bool joinable() const noexcept {
    return _Thr._Id != 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you peek to see what `std::thread::id` is?

Comment: i have not, yet, in any way. The docs state that the function should return false if called by active thread of execution and the very reason why I begun lurking into this is that is NOT the case. The function compares against 0.

Comment: If it behaves the same way the implementation doesn't matter. If you have a problem using `std::thread` post a new question with a [mre]. The visual studio implementation is correct and works, the problem is highly likely to be in your code

Comment: I'm looking at the implementation of thread by Microsoft I posted a code snippet. It does a comparison against 0 not against the active thread's ID. It's pretty simple. No need to look at my code.

Comment: Not called **by**, called **on** a `std::thread` that is associated with an active thread. Either you are misinterpreting the specification, or the Microsoft implementation. Maybe even both. Either way, it's behaving as specified.

Comment: @Vega4 The implementation has `id() noexcept : _Id(0) {} // id for no thread`.

Comment: I saw that. In any way. That is not what function was supposed to do. For the implementation to be consistent with functional description the value returned should "Check if the std::thread object identifies an active thread of execution" which is simply not true since it does simple comparison against 0 in both cases.

Comment: In the very moment I'm in stack-view seeing get_id returning the value of the VERY THREAD being debugged and  joinable() returning true AT THE SAME TIME. what's unclear here

Comment: @Vega4 `_Thr._Id` is `get_id()` and `0` is `std::thread::id()` so `joinable` returns true whenever the thread object you call it on has a non-0 _Id i.e. is active. Not sure which part you are disputing here.

Comment: @dxiv, I'm disputing the part in which the specification states that joinable() should  indicate not whether the read is active (i.e. whose id is !=0) but whether the thread is executing as the CURRENTLY ACTIVE THREAD. According to this a comparison should be done against the currently executing thread id and the particular thread's id. According to the specs it should allow to check IF the  thread attempts to join itself. That's the very purpose of it. Not to check whether it is active or not.

Comment: @Vega4 "*whether the thread is executing by the CURRENTLY ACTIVE THREAD*" That's not what `joinable` does. From the page you linked: "*checks if* ***the std::thread object*** *identifies an active thread of execution*". The thread you call `joinable` ***from*** does not matter.

Comment: in any way, in my interpretation (and I'm not alone in books as well as other places, will provide info soon) the function should be returning a comparison against the active thread ID to allow for a check whether the thread can be joined right now by the executing context. in other words, a comparison against an identifier returned from std::this_thread::get_id() should be performed instead. The very name of the function, besides the documentation, written in pretty clear English suggests this.

Comment: No, `joinable` tells you whether the thread has been started and not yet been joined, it makes no guarantee that you can call `join` from the current thread, if that is stated somewhere then it's wrong

Comment: If you think the implementation is non-conforming then report a problem on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: “The docs state that the function should return false if called by active thread of execution” - no, they literally say the opposite.

Comment: @Vega4 You misunderstood what `joinable` does and is meant for. See for example [When should you use std::thread::joinable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924503/when-should-you-use-stdthreadjoinable) and the links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The quoted requirement says "returns true if `get_id() != std::thread::id()`"

To put this in code, the test for an object of type `std::thread` named `thr` is:

```
thr.get_id() != std::thread::id()
```

Note that `std::thread::id()` is simply a default-constructed object of type `std::thread::id`. It has the following properties:

```
std::thread thr;             // thr.get_id() == std::thread::id()
std::thread thr1(something); // thr.get_id() != std::thread::id()
thr1.detach();               // thr.get_id() == std::thread::id()
```

You get the id of the **currently executing** thread by calling `std::this_thread::get_id()`, not `std::thread::id()` (yes, the names look similar, and can be confusing)

Ultimately, calling `joinable()` on a thread object simply tells you whether a call to `join()` on that object would be valid. If calling `join()` isn't valid, calling it will throw an exception.

As to the implementation, I wrote the Dinkumware implementation, which is the base for Microsoft's code (they might have changed it in the past few years). The standard doesn't say what the contents of `std::thread::id` should be. In the Dinkumware implementation it just holds an unsigned integer value. For a thread that's not joinable that value is 0; for a thread that's joinable it's a value other than 0. So implementing `joinable()` by comparing with 0 is correct.